# Continuous data save & reload - best practice

Tags: angularjs, architecture

I've just started working on the financial web app which was implemented a few years ago in AngularJS with .NET API as a backend.  The app contains a number forms collecting data from the user, then recalculating the result after each change and displaying the results on the screen. This has to happen without clicking the save button. At the moment the data is one large object which is sent to the API after each field change and once the save is completed it runs 3 requests to get the new calculations. I'm trying to optimize it and improve performance and I was wondering if there is any standard/best practice for this kind of systems?

Comment: Well, the obvious that comes to mind is to refactor into more granular tasks. Rather than `update(document)` switch to `changeSection(documentSection)`, etc. or whatever level of granularity makes sense. Move away from CRUD and embraced task-based use cases. CRUD is not only bad for performance, but also highly increases the scope of concurrency conflicts.

Comment: there can't be a general statement here for your particular scenario; depends upon the requirements really; maybe each field change (and its impact on other fields) needs to be recorded server-side... this is a vague question given the information...